# How to do a Update/Merge/Patch to a SharePoint list with SharePoint_api

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I want to do a Update to a SharePoint list. I read the headers have to include `"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"` and the type should be `POST`. I dont know if `"IF-MATCH": "*"` is required to have a etag or not. When I delete an item the `"IF-MATCH": "*"` is not required to have a etag. Here is my code:

```
function UpdateBooking(ajaxData) {
  var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Bokningar')/items`;
  //requestHeaders
  var requestHeaders = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
    "IF-MATCH": "*",
    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
  }

  //Data
  var data = {
    __metadata: {
      "type": "SP.Data.BokningarListItem"
    },
    Title: ajaxData.Title,
    EventDate: ajaxData.EventDate,
    EndDate: ajaxData.EndDate,
    Description: ajaxData.Description,
    IsBlock: ajaxData.IsBlock,
    Milj_x00f6_: ajaxData.Milj_x00f6_,
    Program: ajaxData.Program
  };

  //requestBod
  var requestBody = JSON.stringify(data);

  //Post
  var post = jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    headers: requestHeaders,
    data: requestBody
  });

  //Done
  post.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {});
  //Fail
  post.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {});
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The type SP.ListItemEntityCollection does not support HTTP PATCH method."}}}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I wasnt supplying the id in the URL.

```
    var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Bokningar')/items('${id}')`;
```